# Why is electricity turning off as soon as fixture is connected

Tags: electrical

I have an older home where the vanity light fixture wires came out of the wall (with no box). I've decided to change the fixture and have also added an electrical box. Now When I turn the switch on, the pen tester gives me the beeping, so I must have electricity coming in. The problem is as soon as soon as I connect the wires for the light fixture, for some reason the electricity is gone (I put the tester on the hot wire and nothing). What might be causing this?

In the interest of full disclosure:

1. No breakers are tripping (I don't have to reset anything, as soon as I remove the fixture the wire is hot again).
2. The wires are not crossed
3. The fixture is working fine (I've connected it elsewhere and it works).

Thanks in advance for all your help.. I know I've likely made a silly mistake, and really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possibly bad connection somewhere.  Check resistance from panel to fixture (Non-electricfied) and compare hot to neutral resistances.

Comment: Have you checked the voltage with a voltmeter or multimeter?

Answer (score 2):

In layman's terms: "Pen testers" will detect an induced voltage in a conductor. Similar to a static voltage. As soon as you put a load on that conductor the voltage does not have any power behind it so it disappears. (Imagine trying to use a 9 volt battery to start your car. There is voltage there, but very little power.) If you have a solenoid meter (wiggy) or a digital multimeter you will get a more accurate reading. Which apparently is zero, since when you connect the fixture the voltage disappears.

Recheck your wiring. If you added an electrical box I would suspect that first. Caution, a white wire running to a switch is NOT a neutral wire. It is used to supply the switch with power and the black returns from the switch. The white should be re-identified with tape as black.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your help. My wires are very basic: one white, one black, and one copper at the fixture and two blacks (at the switch).

I managed to spend a couple of hours and actually figure out the issue. It was simply the switch. It was a dimming type of switch and I'm assuming it must have some sort of a fuse or something built-in. I am assuming I didn't remove the original fixture properly and somehow manged to affect the built-in fuse. The net affect is every time a load is introduced to the circuit it automatically trips (hence when I didn't have the bulbs connected I had current in the circuit, which I consider to be rather bizarre). To verify this, I changed the switch and everything worked well. I also tried installing the faulty switch elsewhere and got the same result.

Now I'm sure there is a much more scientific explanation to all of this, but I'm glad my lights are on! :)

Thanks again everyone.
-J